# How to setup jade includes with gulp-jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am currently using gulp-jade and I am struggling on how to setup Jade includes in my gulpfile.js.(For clarification, I am referring to this here http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/) The following is the code in my gulpfile.js

```js
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify      = require('gulp-uglify');
var jade        = require('gulp-jade');
var jshint      = require('gulp-jshint');
var fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include');
var reload      = browserSync.reload;


//compile jade to html
gulp.task('templates', function() {

    var YOUR_LOCALS = {};

    gulp.src('./app/jade/*.jade')
        .pipe(jade({
            locals: YOUR_LOCALS
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});

//reload files, once jade compilation happens

gulp.task('jade-watch', ['templates'], reload);


//Sass task for live injecting into all browsers

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('./app/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

//Separate task for the reaction to js files make change even without compilation and what not
gulp.task('compress', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/js/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('js-watch', ['compress'], reload);

//Serve and watch the scss/jade files for changes

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'templates', 'compress'], function () {

    browserSync({server: './dist'});

    gulp.watch('./app/**/*.jade', ['jade-watch']);
    gulp.watch('./app/scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./app/js/*.js', ['js-watch']);

});
```

I know it is quite a bit to parse through. I am hoping it is a standard something, that won't take too long. If you are interested in seeing the entire file structure, it can be seen at my github here https://github.com/CharlieGreenman/Gulp-with-foundation-and-sass

Thank you, and any help would be more than appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was really simple. There were one thing I was doing wrong

1. I was using includes ../includes/head instead of include ../includes/head (using includes actually worked for me in grunt, upon further research I saw I was using it wrong for gulp.).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Gulp plugin that simplifies your includes by allowing you to add some arbitrary paths to resolve includes and extends to, so you don't have to worry so much about relative pathing. Take a look: https://github.com/tomlagier/gulp-jade-modules

Comment: Love the idea. For the record, I have moved onto using node/npm exclusively without the use of gulp, or grunt. I have not looked back since :)